# Check if all button is disabled in a groupbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I already add button click event to disable the button I clicked. Now I want to check if all buttons in my groupbox are disabled, then it will show message box "You Win".

[image]

I already tried to code it but it didn't work well. The message box show every time I click the button if at least one button is disabled.

```
foreach (Button bu in gbxGame.Controls)    
{
    if (bu.Enabled == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You Win")
    }
}
```

Is there any way to check if "all" button in groupbox is disabled ?

Comment: You can use LINQ and ALL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A LINQ All approach:

```
if(gbxGame.Controls.OfType<Button>().All(b => !b.Enabled))
  MessageBox.Show("You win");
```

`Controls` could be any control within the groupbox; it looks like you only have Buttons in there right now but in case it changes, we can ask for only controls of type Button, and then ask if they are "all not enabled"; `b` is an individual button. LINQ will visit them all and return `true` if all of them are `Enabled==false` otherwise it will return false

Answer (score 1):

You can try Linq [`All()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-5.0)

> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

```
//This will check all controls available in group box
if(gbxGame.Controls.All(x => !x.Enabled))
   MessageBox.Show("All controls in group box are disabled");
```

If you want to filter all buttons before checking enabled or not, then use @Caius Jard solution.